# Creating models from oracle database using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to simply generate models from my database, I can connect to my database using server explorer but when I get to entity framework wizard it doesn't show my data connection nor it allows to add an oracle database.

I have read about oracle developer tools for visual studio, but I don't have admin privileges on that pc is there anything else I could do or am I missing something? (maybe some nuget packages that would help me?)

Here as can be seen on the left I'm connected to my database:
[image]
Database wizard not showing my connection:

[image]
And here when I click new Connection: oracle database is not an option.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use the Entity Framework Power tools to reverse engineer the code first classes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj593170(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html

Comment: I've mentioned it in the question that I know about it but I don't have admin privileges and are there any other options for me?

Comment: No, you must install the above tool or get somebody to do that for you